# How do you trim a string that might be null in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-7

I have a string in linq which is loaded from xml, that attribute or element is optional, but I want to trim the string because the xml file can be written manually like this.

```
<text>Hello World</text>
```

or like this

```
<text>
    hello world
<text>
```

the later will create the new line characters before and afterwards which i want trimming.

I tried to do

```
QuestionText = (string)query.Element("text").ToString().Trim()
```

but that crashes the app when that element is not present.

Comment: It's worth adding to your question if you want a "trimmed null" to be null or string.Empty. You are getting answers that can go either way.

Comment: Note that `query.Element("text").ToString()` does not return `" Hello World "` but `"<text> Hello World </text>"`. This is probably not what you want, but led to many answers suggesting how to trim `"<text> Hello World </text>"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QuestionText = query.Element("text")!=null ? query.Element("text").Value.Trim() : string.Empty;
```

Comment: this helped, but rather than ToString (which wrap it in the xml element i used .value and missed the last ";" for valid. great thanks.

Comment: It works, but why evaluate twice uselessly? Suppose another thread is cutting the element text, you'll have an exception.

Comment: @Mario - its just one way of doing it, i assumed that as it was a wp7 app the file would be downloaded / loaded from the file system into memory then processed. The file could be locked completely if another thread had it open. If performance is paramount then searching for the element once is a better option. The key is really just to check whether the element exists before trying to call a function on it

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible this in WP7?

```
QuestionText = ((string)query.Element("text") ?? string.Empty).Trim();
```

Cheers

Comment: QuestionText = ((string)query.Element("text")?.Value ?? string.Empty).Trim();

Comment: @Wildview I don't think it is necessary to specify the `Value` property: the explicit cast to `string` already extracts the inner text.

Answer (score 1):

I might be tempted to make an extension method for XElement

```
public static class XElementExtensions
{
  public static string TrimmedValue(this XElement elem)
  {
     if(elem == null)
        return null; // or, possibly String.Empty depending on your requirement.
     if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(elem.Value))
        return elem.Value
     return elem.Value.Trim();
  }
}
```

Usage then:

```
QuestionText = query.Element("text").TrimmedValue()
```

Comment: Note that `query.Element("text")` returns null when the `<text>` element cannot be found. Checking `elem.Value` for null throws a NullReferenceException in this case.

Comment: how do you add this extension method?

Comment: @Joseph - you just add that class anywhere in your project and make sure you have a `using` for it wherever you want to use it. See [Extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with returning an empty string on null, How about?

> QuestionText = (query.Element("text")+"").Trim()

[I use this other places to convert null strings, but of course since the question is ambiguous as to what to do with nulls/empty's this could be different than what you need]

Answer (score 0):

firstly, don't cast a string to a string.

How about this...

```
string QuestionText = "";
if(query.Element("text") != null)
   QuestionText = query.Element("text").ToString().Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
QuestionText = Convert.ToString(query.Element("text")).Trim();
```